Creating a window using GLFW and Metal on macOS creates two windows?
Whenever I try and create a window, it creates two windows directly on top of each other and gives this error when I move them:
CLIENT ERROR: TUINSRemoteViewController does not override -viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: and thus cannot react to catastrophic errors beyond logging them

Here is what my code looks like:
mtl_engine.mm
#include "mtl_engine.hpp"

void MTLEngine::init() {
    initDevice();
    initWindow();
}

void MTLEngine::run() {
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(glfwWindow)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

void MTLEngine::cleanup() {
    glfwTerminate();
    metalDevice->release();
}

void MTLEngine::initDevice() {
    metalDevice = MTL::CreateSystemDefaultDevice();
}

void MTLEngine::initWindow() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    glfwWindow = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Metal Engine", NULL, NULL);
    if (!glfwWindow) {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    metalWindow = glfwGetCocoaWindow(glfwWindow);
    metalLayer = [CAMetalLayer layer];
    metalLayer.device = (__bridge id<MTLDevice>)metalDevice;
    metalLayer.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
    metalWindow.contentView.layer = metalLayer;
    metalWindow.contentView.wantsLayer = YES;
}

mtl_engine.hpp
#pragma once

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#import <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_COCOA
#import <GLFW/glfw3native.h>

#include <Metal/Metal.hpp>
#include <Metal/Metal.h>
#include <QuartzCore/CAMetalLayer.hpp>
#include <QuartzCore/CAMetalLayer.h>
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.hpp>

class MTLEngine {
public:
    void init();
    void run();
    void cleanup();

private:
    void initDevice();
    void initWindow();

    MTL::Device* metalDevice;
    GLFWwindow* glfwWindow;
    NSWindow* metalWindow;
    CAMetalLayer* metalLayer;
};

main.mm
#include "mtl_engine.hpp"

int main() {

    MTLEngine engine;
    engine.init();
    engine.run();
    engine.cleanup();

    return 0;
}

mtl_implementation.cpp
#define NS_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define CA_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define MTL_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <Foundation/Foundation.hpp>
#include <Metal/Metal.hpp>
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.hpp>


I suspect you are following this tutorial:
https://metaltutorial.com/Lesson%201%3A%20Hello%20Metal/1.%20Hello%20Window/
If so, clone the original project from the repo of that tutorial and try building that project and see if you encounter with the same issue or not.
I ran it and it was fine however, your mac terminal wants to run it too (in my case iterm tried to run it 2 times) and it will give you 2 or 3 windows because of that. I think it's maybe a bug, I don't know, I'm trying to learn from this source too. Maybe closing the terminal will fix it.

Yes, I’ve tried cloning the repo to no luck. I’ve also tried running an SDL2 project that I know works and it also runs two windows. I’m not running it multiple times, so I’m thinking it’s a configuration issue on my end but I don’t even know where I would start to fix that

Since I can't replicate the exact problem, I think it's on your end. Because of that I can't fine a solution for it. But I suspect it's because of terminal. Can you try building it inside terminal instead of inside the XCode?
